# How to execute sql code to query snowflake database from streamlit

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I connected to my companies snowflake database with streamlit
I used a secrets.toml file to store the necessary info
Now how do I go about executing queries? I created the session successfully.
I looked through documentation and saw that I could use the command
session.sql("""SHOW GRANTS TO USER "John.doe@hotmail.com"; """)
However how would I display the results of this code?

Answer (score 0):

You assign the query to a dataframe and then display the df in your app using whatever of the available methods is appropariate e.g.

```
df = conn.query('SELECT * from mytable;', ttl=600)
st.write(df)
```

Comment: You can't use a show SHOW GRANTS TO USER "John.doe@hotmail.com. It gives an error saying that  Failed to fetch a Pandas Dataframe. The error is: to_pandas() did not return a Pandas DataFrame. If you use session.sql(...).to_pandas(), the input query can only be a SELECT statement. Or you can use session.sql(...).collect() to get a list of Row objects for a non-SELECT statement, then convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are running (updating your question with the actual code would be helpful) - but what about the error message is not clear?